# Trying to download export of GSuite. Receive 'OSError: The directory name is invalid.' when it hits folders named "

Tags: export, google-workspace, gsutil

I am trying to download the data of all of my users before we close out our Google Suite account. I have created the export. I installed Google Cloud SDK Shell and authenticated to it.. I run `gsutil cp -r gs://takeout-export-xxxxxxxxxxxx C:\GExport` and it downloads all of the folders that come before 'R' but when it hits the first "Resource: -xxx" folder, it fails with

> OSError: The directory name is invalid.

These folders don't seem to have overly useful data so I even tried deleting them (from the website interface) but they always fail to delete.

What gives? How can I go about downloading all of the user folders without doing so one at a time, manually?

Edit:

I tried selecting each folder (minus the problem folders) in the website GUI and select download so it gave me commands to download those folders. I tried to copy/paste those commands into GCloud SDK Shell but it doesn't seem to work. It fails when it hits the second line (the first folder to download). Not sure of the proper syntax to attempt to download many folders apparently (and Google's suggested commands are not correct).

Answer (score 1):

Ended up giving up doing it the "right" way and modified the command to be many lines, grabbing each folder one at a time, copy/pasted the commands into GCloud SDK and letting them downloading one at a time.  Notepad++ is so useful

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and the answer here helped me save a lot of time.
I ended up writing a powershell script to do this. I've included it below to help anyone coming across this issue:

```
# Define the base URL for the Google Cloud Storage folders
$baseURL = "gs://takeout-export-xxx/xxx/Resource: "

# Define the IDs of the folders to download
$folderIDs = @(
    "-xxx",
    ...
)

# For each folder ID, create a local folder and download the contents of the GCS folder
foreach ($folderID in $folderIDs) {
    # Create a local folder name by replacing the ":" character with an underscore
    $localFolderName = $folderID -replace ":", "_"
    $localFolderName = "Resource " + $localFolderName

    # Create the local folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $localFolderName)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $localFolderName
    }

    # Change to the local folder
    Set-Location -Path $localFolderName

    # Construct the full URL of the GCS folder
    $fullURL = $baseURL + $folderID

    # List all the files in the GCS folder
    $files = gsutil ls "`"$fullURL`""

    # For each file, download it and replace any illegal characters in the filename
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        # Get the filename and replace any illegal characters
        $fileName = Split-Path -Leaf $file
        $safeFileName = $fileName -replace ":", "_"

        # Download the file
        gsutil cp "`"$file`"" $safeFileName

        # Pause for 1 seconds to check for errors
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }

    # Change back to the parent folder
    Set-Location -Path ..
}
```